# Multiplying a single sound effect

Tags: sound-effects

I have a situation I'm currently struggling with. I;m looking for a some creative way of multiplying a single sound to the effect of hearing dozen of them. My case is particularly some dull sound hit into many hits that reflect these many things falling and hitting the surface.

If you got some ideas, maybe some specific effects and ways you do that and you're that keen to share it I would be really grateful.

Kind regards!

Comment: hi pandroid, can you update on what it is exactly that you try to recreate? is it fictional or more realistic?

Comment: Well, it's actually for CGI video where there is a lot a vegetables start falling on a surface in a slo-motion. I have a few single sounds that fits and looking for a way of doing it sounds like dozen of them.

Comment: Recording more variations is going to give you the best result. We are well tuned to hearing repetition, even with pitch adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

General tips for making more variations from handful of samples:

-Adjust the samplerate of sound and then pitchshift the sound closer to the original sound. For example stretch so that it sounds 2 semitones higher than original and then pitchshift -2 semitones.

-Create new variations by combining attack and tail of a different sounds.

-Both of the above.

When placing samples to timeline avoid playing samples with same sources on top of each other or otherwise you will get nasty phasing issues or noticeable repetition.
Having slightly different samplerate or small amount of pitchshifting or timestretching on each sample can also help.

Recording more variations would be best option though.

Comment: Also remember to change the panning position, and even doing a stereo delay with a different value on left vs. right to simulate binaural audio.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from pitch shifting, i'll usually change the attack of the sound, sometimes just fading it in slightly, maybe time stretching some a little bit, or fading them out faster.  You could also eq them a bit differently and just be sure to mix up the different versions in your edit.